# Python subprocess module - unexpected behavior

Tags: python, c, subprocess

I need to interface a C console program (as subprocess) with Python using stdin/stdout.

the C program is more o less it:

```
    tmp = 0.0;  
    printf("\ninput>>");
    scanf_s("%f",&tmp);
    printf ("\ninput was: %f",tmp);

    tmp = 0.0;
    printf("\ninput>>");
    scanf_s("%f",&tmp);
    printf ("\ninput was: %f",tmp);

    tmp = 0.0;
    printf("\ninput>>");
    scanf_s("%f",&tmp);
    printf ("\ninput was: %f",tmp);
```

Using python subprocess module I need to read data from this program, the write something, then read again and so on. I used the following code:

```
>>> p=subprocess.Popen(['C:\T.exe'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> o,i=communicate('123\n')
```

the output of o is:

```
input>>
input was: 123.000000
input>>
input was: 0.000000
input>>
input was: 0.000000
```

I would expect the subprocess to wait on input until another o,i=communicate() call. Why it is proceding to the end of the program without any input? how to fix it?

Comment: This has bitten me once in the past as well. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There can be at most one call to `communicate()` for each process, because `communicate()` waits for the child process to terminate. To repeatedly read and write from/to a process's standard streams, use the `stdout` and `stdin` attributes of the `Popen` class.

Comment: if i use p.stdout.read(10) then the python shell is not responding until I close the process manually. then it outputs ''. same with .readline and .readlines. What that could be?

Comment: `read(10)` waits until it encounters EOF or has read 10 bytes. I have little experience with that, but you should use `select` or background threads to poll and read from the streams. There is also a warning about deadlocks in the `subprocess` documentation.

Comment: what kind of "select" do you mean?

Comment: btw, p.stdin.write() works perfect. and all p.stdout.read*() works fine only after termination of the subprocess.